# ios CocoaPods Could not automatically select an Xcode project. Specify one in your Podfile like so

Tags: ios, xcode, cocoapods

I try to run `pod install` command in my project directory. But it throws an error like below:

```
[!] Could not automatically select an Xcode project. Specify one in your Podfile like so:

    project 'path/to/Project.xcodeproj'
```

**My project directory:**

```
 - MyApp
 - MyApp.xcodeproj
 - MyApp.xcworkspace
 - Podfile
 - Podfile.lock
 - Pods
```

**podFile**

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '9.0'
use_frameworks!
project '/Users/dev4/Developer/iOS/MyApp/MyApp.xcodeproj'

target 'MyApp' do
  pod 'Gifu'
  pod 'Alamofire'
  pod 'SwiftyJSON'
  pod 'Fabric'
  pod 'Crashlytics'
  pod 'IQKeyboardManagerSwift'
  pod 'NVActivityIndicatorView'
  pod 'M13Checkbox'
  pod 'Kingfisher'
  pod 'KMPlaceholderTextView'
  pod 'WDImagePicker', :git => 'https://github.com/justwudi/WDImagePicker', :tag => 'master'
  pod 'RSBarcodes_Swift', '~> 0.1.9'
  pod 'CCMPopup'
  pod 'Cosmos', '~> 1.0'
  pod 'FLAnimatedImage', '~> 1.0'
  pod 'Google/Analytics'
  pod 'Reveal-iOS-SDK', :configurations => ['Debug']
end
```

I added code part "**project 'myprojectpath/to/Project.xcodeproj'**". But it didn't work. How can I solve this?

Comment: open terminal cd file path , then pod install now try

Comment: Sorry. I think, terminal has directory cache. So, it hasn't seen podfiles. I run cd.. and cd directory it works. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

I had copied my previous project with changing the App package name.When i came through this issue i go through my project structure and get to know that i have two .xcodeproj file .After deleting the old one i get rid of this issue.

Answer (score 1):

The path that you specify should be relative to your Podfile. So, if your Podfile is in "/Users/dev4/Developer/iOS/", then you should use:

```
project 'MyApp/MyApp.xcodeproj'
```